# collapsible header long text issue

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

the problem is when entering long text for header, the title get wide off the screen. please see the following screenshot 
[image]

```
var element =''+
                 '<div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="b" align="right" dir="rtl">'+
                 '<h4 onclick="changeText(this);" align="right" dir="rtl">'+$(node).find("NoteText").text()+'</h4> '+
                 '<table border =  "0"> '+
                 '<tr align = "right" dir = "rtl"><td> اسم :'+$(node).find("Name").text()+'</td></tr><tr align = "right" dir = "rtl"><td> العمل :'+$(node).find("Phone").text()+'</td></tr>'+
                 '</table>'+
                 '</div>';
                 $("#set").prepend(element).collapsibleset('refresh');
```

CSS:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-text{
    white-space : normal !important;

}​
          .ui-collapsible h4 .ui-btn-inner{
            direction: rtl !important;
            text-align: right !important;
          }
```

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
var element =''+
                 '<div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="b" align="right" dir="rtl">'+
                 '<p><h4 onclick="changeText(this);" align="right" dir="rtl">'+$(node).find("NoteText").text()+'</p></h4> '+
                 '<table border =  "0"> '+
                 '<tr align = "right" dir = "rtl"><td> اسم :'+$(node).find("Name").text()+'</td></tr><tr align = "right" dir = "rtl"><td> العمل :'+$(node).find("Phone").text()+'</td></tr>'+
                 '</table>'+
                 '</div>';
                 $("#set").prepend(element).collapsibleset('refresh');
```

I just added

and it works fine with me